# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am working on a web project using reactjs and I faced some problems exactly 2.
The first one is when I want to send a request to my api using axios.

This is what I have done so far:

```js
import auction1 from '../../Images/auction1.png'
import {useState} from 'react';
import './HomeScreen.css'
import {Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = ()=>{

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const [img, setImg] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
    const [deadline, setDeadLine] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");


    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);


    const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();

        try{
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            };

            const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:7500/api/users/posts"
            ,{name, img, deadline, price, description},config);

            console.log(data);

        }catch{
            setError(error.response.data.message);
        }
    };



    
    return(
        <div className="container bg">
            <img src ={auction1} className='landing-image' />
            <div style={{marginLeft:460}}> 
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                    Create Post
                </Button>
            </div> 
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Create Post</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <form >
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Post Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"
                                value={name} onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Post Images:</label>
                                <input type="file" className="form-control" multiple onChange="readURL(this)" accept="Image/*" 
                                value={img} onChange={(e)=> setImg(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <label>Price:</label>
                                <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="TND"
                                value={price} onChange={(e)=> setPrice(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>DeadLine:</label>
                                <input type="date" className="form-control"
                                value={deadline} onChange={(e)=> setDeadLine(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Description:</label>
                                <textarea className="form-control" rows="3"
                                value={description} onChange={(e)=> setDescription(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleClose} >
                            Save Post
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )

};

export default HomeScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The Piece of code above is my Home Component in which I have a popup form that shows up when I click on create post button then after filling the form I am getting this error on the console:
[The error I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DimF4.png)

And a last thing even with unsuccessful submit when I click on the create button again to refill the form I get this type of error:
[The second error I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NC8x.png)
I would be so grateful if you give a hand on this.

Comment: why is your catch missing `catch (error) {`

Comment: Since you do not have error defined it is reading `error` from `const [error, setError] = useState(false);` and that does not have `data`

Comment: The Axios `error.response` is nullable / optional. See https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: The default content-type when posting JS objects with Axios is `application/json`. Why do developers feel the need to set this all the time?